# GLM: Get rotational axis from the matrix

Tags: c++, vector, glm-math, direction

I have a `glm::mat4 matrix`  and I have performed several rotations and translations on that matrix. How can I get the rotational axis of that matrix in Normalized form?

It should be `Unity3D` equivalent of `gameObject.transform.forward` or `gameObject.transform.right`

Comment: Have You seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463487/obtain-rotation-axis-from-rotation-matrix-and-translation-vector-in-opencv

Comment: There is no such thing as rotational axis in your matrix.... the rotation axis is defined by the transform applied on it not in the matrix applied to. But you can extract basis vectors and position easily (I think that is what you wanted) see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)